# How to merge multiple file geodatabases into one file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, gps, merge, trimble, juno

I have created a file geodatabase that has several feature data sets, feature classes, and domains.  I have created a map with the file geodatabase added to it, converted the map to ARCPAD AXF format and **copied the map to several Junos changing the name for each Juno unit**.  Data is being successfully collected.

My question is: **How do I merge all these seperate geodatabases from the Junos into the central file geodatabase that I created originally?**

Answer (score 4):

First, welcome to the site!

To check your data back in you need to run [Check-In](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/Get_Data_from_ArcPad/00s10000006r000000/) (form the [Data Manager Toolbar](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#//00s10000007t000000)) for each of the AXF files. This will check modifications (edit, create & delete) back into the parent Geodatabase.

**Note** that if there are any conflicts, last in wins (ie, new data will overwrite existing data even if that data had changed since checkout). If this is a concern you should use [replica geodatabases](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002700000022000000.htm) to check-out from and use ArcGIS Desktop tools to manage conflicts before committing edits to your original geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty template geodatabase but the correct field/domains/subtypes - then use **APPEND** Tool.

(you can just load all fields with the NO_TEST option see below)

> **If the Schema Type TEST is specified, the schema (field definitions) of the input datasets must match that of the target dataset in order
>   for the features to be appended**. If the Schema Type NO_TEST is
>   specified, input dataset schema (field definitions) do not have to
>   match the target dataset. However, any fields from the input datasets
>   that do not match the fields of the target dataset will not be mapped
>   to the target dataset unless the mapping is explicitly set in the
>   Field Map control

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000